# Method to solve A = mod( Bn, C)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I go by solving an equation of the general form.

> A = mod ( Bn, C )

Solve for n knowing A, B and C

Where B and C are Natural numbers and A and n are whole numbers. Also the greatest common denominator between B and C is 1.

Comment: This notation is nonstandard. Do you mean that $A \equiv Bn \pmod C$ and $0 \le A < C$?

Comment: Yes and thank you for the question that adds clarification. I have trouble writing it down and in simplifying I forgot to include the bounds of A.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I wasn't referring to the distinction between whole/natural numbers but rather the $\text{mod}$ notation: $\text{mod} (k,n)$ is used in programming languages to return a number $r$ such that $r \equiv k \pmod n$ and $0 \le r < n$.

Comment: So $A=C$ is not allowed?

Comment: Correct. A can't equal C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \not \in [0, C-1]$ then clearly there is no solution. Otherwise, we have

$$A \equiv Bn \pmod C.$$

Since $(B,C) = 1$, the inverse $B^{-1}$ exists modulo $C$, and we can multiply it on both sides to get:

$$AB^{-1} \equiv n \pmod C.$$

So your problem is simply to find the inverse $B^{-1}$, which can be done using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you are misunderstanding the notation. See my comments clarifying this above. In Excel, for example, $\text{mod}$ is a function, so $\text{mod}(16,5)=1$, $\text{mod}(7,7)=0$, and so on.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This agrees with my answer. I'm not sure what your argument is.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Also, it is $A$ that must be in the range $[0,C-1]$. Obviously $C$ is never in this range.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think this remark is just missing in your first two lines of your answer (you are using $A\equiv Bn \bmod C$, and not the other notation). Otherwise there can be solutions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am using $A \equiv Bn \pmod C$ after having established with the OP in the comments above that the greater context of the problem is $A = \text{mod}(Bn,C)$ in the programming sense. I think it is clear.

Comment: Yes, of course it is clear. Still, it would be nice to have this not only in the comments (which are often deleted later), but in your answer.